# Python constructor with many optional parameters

Tags: python

I'm calling a class in python with many optional parameters. The reason I constructed then constructor this way is because I want to have two possibilities to to create an instance of an employee object.

```
def __init__(self, ssn=None, familyssn=None, first_name=None, last_name=None, middle_name=None, email=None, mobile_phone=None, phone=None, department=None, salary=None, employee_list=None):
  self.employee_list = employee_list or []

  dict_of_emp = {}
  list_of_emp = []
  self.ssn = ssn
  self.familyssn = familyssn
  self.first_name = first_name
  self.last_name = last_name
  self.middle_name = middle_name
  self.email = email
  self.mobile_phone = mobile_phone
  self.phone = phone
  self.department = department
  self.salary = salary

  list_of_emp.append(ssn)
  list_of_emp.append(familyssn)
  list_of_emp.append(first_name)
  list_of_emp.append(last_name)
  list_of_emp.append(middle_name)
  list_of_emp.append(email)
  list_of_emp.append(mobile_phone)
  list_of_emp.append(phone)
  list_of_emp.append(department)
  list_of_emp.append(salary)

  #print "listi i smid: ", list_of_emp
  Employee.empCount += 1

  print "loop through list in constructor: ", employee_list
```

is this the only way to call the constructor ?

```
emp = Employee(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, list_of_list_emp_to_register)
```

I find it rather ugly syntax !

Comment: No, you do not need all those `None`s. You should note the documentation on [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). Also, what is the `list_of_list_emp_to_register`?

Comment: You could also change your last optional of `employee = None` to `employee = []`, although there may be some consternations with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The options, are as you said optional.  Thus `Employee()` is equivalent to filling in all the `None`s.  That is the point of `ssn=None` etc.

To specify the last argument simply say

```
emp = Employee(employee_list=list_of_list_emp_to_register)
```